# unable to display error message in view using express validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, express-validator

I am using axios, [express validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-error-messages.html) and [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) for the function of letting a user change their password in their account area. The field I am checking against is the one where the user needs to type in their existing password. It then hashes their input and checks it against the database hashed password. When doing other validation I am able to get the error message response back via axios but for this will not:

```
body("currentPass")
.custom((value, { req }) => {
  return User.findOne({ _id: req.user }).then(userDoc => {
    bcrypt.compare(value, userDoc.password).then(domatch => {
      if (!domatch) {
        return Promise.reject("no match");
      } 
    });
  });
})
```

The error I get is:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: no match Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

If I add a catch block then when validation fails the catch block fires instead of the Promise.reject

```
body("currentPass")
.custom((value, { req }) => {
  return User.findOne({ _id: req.user })
   .then(userDoc => {
    bcrypt.compare(value, userDoc.password)
    .then(domatch => {
      if (!domatch) {
        return Promise.reject("no match");
      } 
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('catch block error');
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Try `return bcrypt.compare()`

Comment: @PrerakSola, that seems to work! Please could you add it as an answer so I can accept it.